# Interaction between my webapp and smart contract

Tags: remix, react, nft, transfer, frontend

I am experimenting for the first time with smart contracts and NFT stuff.

So I am at the point where I have a react webapp with metamask integration. The user can connect his wallet. I want to implement NFTs as reward for achievements that I minted myself. So like there is a trigger that the user gets a possibility/metamask popup to claim the NFT at the moment.

I already managed with tutorials to deploy smart contracts and mint NFTs with Remix.

But I am stuck somehow how to implement this in my code and would kindly ask for some hints where to look at? I am thankful for any help!

Comment: Who will mint those tokens? each user, some privileged users. Who will decide when a token can be minted? and under what conditions?

Comment: You might start with my [answer here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/102960/73314). It shows basic contract interaction with your dapp.

Comment: @Ismael tokens would be already minted and are then "only" waiting to be sent to the user when he meets a certain condition in the game. Simplest condition would be level completed -> user gets possibility to claim

Comment: @defikintaro thank you I am looking into it right now, so basically I need the ABI from the contract and import it as one of the first steps?

Comment: Exactly, ABI is how you interact with your contract. Additionally you've to provide your identity as a signer for calling write functions(ie not 'view') of your contract.